# PHP function to return first results only

Tags: php, return

I'm trying to create a simple function to return only the first set of results from a query but I'm getting the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /Users/MAMP_SITES/website/classes/DB.php on line 78
```

Here is the code that causes the error:

```
$user = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('username', '=', 'rich'));

if(!$user->count()) {
    echo 'No user';
} else {
foreach($user->results() as $user) {
    echo $user->first()->username;
}
}
```

Here are the relevant functions from DB.php:

```
public function results() {
    return $this->_results;
}

public function first() {
    return $this->results()[0]; // This is line 78 where the error is
}
```

I'm getting this code from a tutorial that may be a little out of date.

Comment: Array dereferencing, only on php > 5.4. What's your php version? `As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.`

Comment: So the tutorial is not a little out of date, actually the opposite :)

Comment: Ahh, so what's the fix? MAMP is running 5.3.14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array dereferencing is only available in more recent PHP versions. To return the first array item you can use the current() function.

```
return current($this->results());
```

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the setting in MAMP to run 5.4.4 and that seems to be the better way to go since the server this will eventually sit on is running 5.4.4 also.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
public function first() {
    $results = $this->results();
    return (sizeof($results)>0 ? $results[0] : null);
}
```

OR

```
public function first() {
    return current( $this->results() );
}
```